# what does the er here stands for?

Tags: python

```
try: 
    os.execvp('sqlite3', args) 
except OSError, er: 
    if er.errno == 2: #file not found 
        raise OSError, _("sqlite3 executable not found. Is it installed?") 
    else: 
        raise 
except: 
    raise
```

In the above code, the `except` statement catches the `OSError` but what does the `er` variable stand for?

EDIT: this one only excepts `OSError`; is there a way to except any error and get the exception object for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`er` is the actual exception object that got caught by the `except` clause.

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, `er` is the instantiated form of the exception, `OSError`.

If it's helpful, here's an alternative, somewhat more explicit syntax, using the `as` keyword:

```
try: 
    os.execvp('sqlite3', args) 
except OSError as er: 
    if er.errno == 2: #file not found 
        raise OSError(_("sqlite3 executable not found. Is it installed?"))
    else: 
        raise 
except: 
        raise
```

Which, to me, says that `er` will be an `OSError`.

As `as er` syntax was added in Python 2.6, by the way.

Comment: Then also you have the fun caveat due to the old `,` syntax where something like `except KeyError, ValueError:` won't do what you might expect at first - it'll catch a `KeyError` and assign it to the local variable `ValueError`. So `except (KeyError, ValueError):` is needed.

Comment: I've also updated the answer to remove the deprecated old-style exception raising (`raise Exception, message`) in favour of the new style (`raise Exception(message)`). If you're going to use the new-style `except .. as` form, you should definitely use the newer raise syntax (which has been supported for longer).

Answer (score 1):

`er` is the exception object itself.

Answer (score 1):

looks like er is an exception object (of type OSError also looks like it holds the errors.
ER probably stands for error.

Comment: @this one only excepts OSError is there a way to except any error and get the exception object for it ?

Comment: you could make a class/structure containing the error types you want OSError,RuntimeError, TypeError, NameError so on that way you could use all data types at once. i'm not sure if python has something like this by default but this may work.